# How to default to single row view when the "Add Row" button is pressed

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am developing an application in Oracle Apex 22.2. The page has an interactive grid. The users can enter information in the different cells. The problem is that 4 out of the 10 fields that they enter are text fields and they mentioned that entering the data in the single row view is easier for them. I would like that when the user presses the Add Row button it adds the row and immediately goes to the Single Row View. If possible when the user clicks save it would be nice if they went back to the report view.

What I managed so far is almost what I need. Overwriting what selection-add-row does allows me to open the single row view after clicking the Add Row button. However, instead of opening the single row view of the blank record it opens the single row view of the first record in the interactive grid.

This was placed in the Initialization JavaScript Function.

```
function(config) { 
config.initActions = function( actions ) {
  actions.remove('selection-add-row');
  actions.add({
    name: "selection-add-row",
    label: "Add row",
    iconBeforeLabel: "true",
    action: function(event, focusElement) {
      let model = $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getCurrentView').model;
        model.insertNewRecord();
        $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getActions').invoke("single-row-view");
    }
  });
}
return config;}
```

These two lines insert the record at the beginning.

```
let model = $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getCurrentView').model;
model.insertNewRecord();
```

This line opens the single-row-view but only on the first record that exists in the interactive grid.

```
$(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getActions').invoke("single-row-view");
```

If I close the single row view and click on add row again it creates a new blank row but it opens the single row view of the previous blank row.

I have been reading the documentation but obviously there is something I am not getting.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a "normal" form for new rows, but an IG for updating rows, so why not implement it that way ?

- Set the "Add Row" attribute in the interactive grid to false so users cannot add new rows (or hide button if you still want to allow copy row) in the IG.
- Create a new page with a form region on the same table. Ideally of page type dialog
- Add a "Add Row" button to redirect to the form page.
- Add an on dialog close action to refresh the interactive grid.

Comment: That is a good idea. I have created dialog pages before. The only detail now is to add a button to the IG that opens that new dialog page. I don't want to add a button outside of the Interactive Grid. Should I ask  a new question?

Comment: New question is best. Its very different from this one and comments don’t have visisbility

Answer (score 0):

Although this solution wont work for my app I will leave the code that does exactly as I asked in case it is useful to someone in the future. I will end up using Koen solution and create a modal dialog.

This will create a new row at the top, select it and open it as single row view. Then the save button on top of saving it goes back to the normal report view. The code that goes back to the report view does nothing if we are already in the report view.

```
function(config) { 
config.initActions = function( actions ) {
  actions.remove('selection-add-row');
  actions.add({
    name: "selection-add-row",
    label: "Add row",
    iconBeforeLabel: "true",
    action: function(event, focusElement) {
     
    // get the model of the interactive grid  
    let model = $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getCurrentView').model;
    // we insert a blank row.
    model.insertNewRecord();
    // get the grid
    let gridView = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews").grid
    // find the record by id, in this case the new record has id t1000.
    let record = model.getRecord( "t1000" ); 
    // select and focus record
    gridView.view$.grid("setSelectedRecords", [record], true); 
    // open the single row view now that the new record is selected
    $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getActions').invoke("single-row-view"); 
        
    }
  });
  actions.remove('save');
  actions.add({
    name: "save",
    label: "Save",
    iconBeforeLabel: "true",
    action: function(event, focusElement) {
    
    // get the model of the interactive grid  
    let model = $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getCurrentView').model;
    // we save the data
    model.save();
    // Up to this point this is the same as the normal save button.
    // But if we are in the single row view saving get us out from there and back into the report.
    $(actions.context).interactiveGrid('getActions').invoke("close-single-row-view");
        
    }
  });
}
return config;}
```